# How to add state while mapping into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array with where i map over and return some checkboxes but i cannot pass the state to each checkbox so i can control the value of each one.

I tried to get the keys of the obj and so i can use them as the name of each checkbox but it didnt worked

```
"extras": [
  { "key": "womens", "value": "Women's" },
  { "key": "mens", "value": "Men's" },
  { "key": "negotiable", "value": "Negotiable" },
  { "key": "withPrice", "value": "With Price" }
]

<FormControlLabel
    label={label}
    labelPlacement={labelPlacement}
    className={classes.formControlLabel}
    control={
      <Checkbox
        defaultChecked={props.defaultChecked}
        name={name}
        value={values}
        onChange={handleChange}
        color="primary"
        inputProps={{
          "aria-label": "primary checkbox"
        }}
      />
    }
  />

const [state, setState] = useState({
  negotiable: false,
  womens: false,
  mens: false,
  withPrice: false
});

const handleCheckboxChange = event => {
  setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};

{extras.map(extra => {
            return (
              <CheckboxForm
                key={extra.key}
                name={extra.key}
                value={extra.key}
                label={extra.value}
                labelPlacement="end"
                handleChange={handleCheckboxChange}
              />
            );
          })}
```

What i am looking for is to make the checkboxes controlled so when i change the value from the state to appear on the UI as well

Comment: How will you be checking the value of the state using a checkbox, if the value is a string?

Comment: Took some time, but here's one way: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-chatelet-bp0nn

Comment: how about: `value={state[extra.key]}`

Comment: @ChrisG nice I had a similar idea, though mine is in a more basic form. https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-frog-ef97q. Still kind of unclear what the OP is trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. It is working perfectly with just a small change for my case. For the create form is perfect, now i will figure out something similar for the search form.